# Best way to initiate socket connection with a nodejs server and keep listening for new events in background in android?

Tags: android, socket.io

I have a Chat app and a backend nodejs server, what is the best way to initiate the socket connection and listen for new messages in background even when the android app is not running ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use express. So first install express
server-side

```
npm install express --save
```

then you have to install socket.io

```
npm install socket.io
```

finally you have to copy this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const server =  app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor up en ${port}`);
});
const socket = require('socket.io');
io = socket(server);
 io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected')
 //This is a example of using sockets
  socket.io('somethingToSendClient', someDataHere)
}
```

Comment: my question is handling the listener in android app

Comment: are u using react-native?